# How to integrate linear trnasformations for probability distributions?

Tags: probability, integration, linear-transformations

I want to fit a probability distribution that exploits linear dependency.

Lets say, for instance, I have three variables X, Y and Z.

I apply the some matrix decomposition to the observations and get the following transformation matrix:
$$
A=
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13}\\
a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23}\\
a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33}\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

I transform my observations to the ICA representations and fit distributions independently over each axis.

Therefore I get the functions $f_1(a_{11}x + a_{21}y + a_{31}z), f_2(a_{12}x + a_{22}y + a_{32}z), f_3(a_{13}x + a_{23}y + a_{33}z)$.

Due to the independence assumption I can now express my density function by $P(X,Y,Z) = f_1 * f_2 * f_3$.
I understand that I can express this function as $A \times \begin{bmatrix}X & Y & Z \end{bmatrix}^T$.

To answer marginal queries I have to integrate, for instance $P(1<X<2, 0<Y<0.5, 3<Z<5) = \int_{X=1}^{X=2} \int_{Y=0}^{Y=0.5} \int_{Z=3}^{Z=5} f_1 * f_2 * f_3 dZ dY dX$. Can someone help me finding a solution for that in for 3 dimensions and perhaps even for N dimensions? Also the functional form of all f is known, it is some form of derivative the empirical CDF, i.e. a mixture of uniform distributions (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empirical_distribution_function).

In this book https://stats.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Probability_Theory/Probability_Mathematical_Statistics_and_Stochastic_Processes_(Siegrist)/00%3A_Front_Matter/03%3A_Table_of_Contents i found theorem 3.7.9 and 3.11.12 related but couldnt find an answer yet.

What is in general the integral over a lineary transformed set of random variables with independent linear transformed distributions?

$$
\int_X \int_Y \int_Z P(X,Y,Z) dZ dY dX = ?
$$

Please let me know if something is missing,

Thanks!

Comment: integration is also linear transformation, you just need to use the basis B=[1 x x² x³ x⁴ ... x^n]. Also different dimensions should be handled separately, so you might want to handle X=[1 0 0}, Y=[0 1 0] and Z=[0 0 1]  separately, one at the time. With the basis B, the integration is simply a matrix you can multiply to it.

Comment: Hm, I don't understand. Can you make an example, how you would express the linear relation and its integral?